# How to read FSM diagram?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, finite-state-machine

How do I read this? I have searched everywhere and I don't know how to read it. It is a machine for calculating if a binary number is divisible by 5...

*apparently*...

(I don't know how to read it, how would I know?).

[image: http://aswitalski.github.io/img/FSM-binary-divisible-by-five.png]

Comment: It takes a word for example 100001. It reads it from left to right. So now you have to follow. First we start at the state who has 2 circles. Which is 0. (Notice that it makes sense because we didnt read anything else yet). So the automata reads a 1. It follows the transition 1 at state 0. So we go to the 1. Now we are at state 1.We read 0.Follow from state 1 the transtion 0. We go to state 2. We read 0 again. So we go to state 4. I think you notice how it goes on  now. The last state will be the remainder.

Comment: Excuse me are you asking how the FSM was created or how to read it ?

Answer (score 0):

Convert FSM to regular expression using the state elimination method. Read more about it [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03573.pdf)